# Cascading dropdown and Select Links to Page onchange

Tags: jquery, html, onchange, html-select

I'm using a script to populate a second Select. Using the values of the second select to pair with first select.

```
    $("#select1").change(function() { 
    if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    $('#select2').html(options);
    });
```

I would like to use onchange on the second select to link to a page. This is what I'm using/would like to use.

```
    <select ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="http://www.apple.com/">Apple</option>
    </select>
```

My question is: How can I put the url in the value of second select when I'm using that value to identify with first select?

Also, when page loads the second select displays all options until selection of first select then it will display only those with matching values.

This is my html:

```
    <div id="location_select">
    <table align="center">
    <tbody><tr>
    <th><label for="select1">Province:</label></th>
    <td>
  <select id="select1" name="select1">
<option select="selected" value="0"></option>
<option value="AB">Alberta</option>
<option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <th><label for="select2">City:</label></th>
    <td>
    <select id="select2" name="select2">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="AB"></option>
    <option value="AB">a</option>
    <option value="AB">b</option>
    <option value="AB">c</option>
    <option value="BC"></option>
    <option value="BC">d</option>
    <option value="BC">e</option>
    <option value="BC">f</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

Comment: thats called cascading dropdowns :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a bit:

Javascript:

```
$("#select2").attr("disabled", true);

$("#select1").change(function() { 
    if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
        $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[id=' + id + ']');
    $('#select2').html(options);
    $("#select2").attr("disabled", false);
});


$("#select2").change(function() { 
    var link = $(this).val();
    alert(link);
});
```

The html:

```
<div id="location_select">
    <table align="center">
    <tbody>
    <th><label class="select_location_label" for="select1">Province:</label></th>
    <td>
  <select id="select1" name="select1">
<option select="selected" value="0"></option>
<option value="AB">Alberta</option>
<option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <th><label class="select_location_label" for="select2">City:</label></th>
    <td>
    <select id="select2" name="select2">
    <option id="0">Select Province first</option>
    <option id="AB" value="http://www.google.com"></option>
    <option id="AB" value="http://www.google.com">a</option>
    <option id="AB" value="http://www.google.com">b</option>
    <option id="AB" value="http://www.google.com">c</option>
    <option id="BC" value="http://www.google.com"></option>
    <option id="BC" value="http://www.google.com">d</option>
    <option id="BC" value="http://www.google.com">e</option>
    <option id="BC" value="http://www.google.com">f</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

See jsfiddle for the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/7qDgZ/1/
That should help you

Comment: OK great, this will do it. Thank you Daniel. As far as disabling the second select on load. If I was to select a city and it links to that page if I use my browser to go back the city I selected will still be selected but it's disabled. I would have to reselect the first select to enable those cities. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I updated the code to prevent this from happening: http://jsfiddle.net/7qDgZ/7/ is this what you need?

Comment: Hey, Yes when I go back the second select will be enabled but it shows all selects again not only those with same value.

Comment: Doesn't quite do it. WIll still show all of options when using broswer back button. Appreciate your help this far Daniel.

Comment: Perhaps on page load can we select id 0 or will the browser back button always have the option last used selected?

Comment: Wonder how much reputation I need to PM you with the websites url?

Comment: Well, it works great as far as the question I asked you answered it completely. 

However, following making a selection and linking me to that page if for any reason I use the browsers back button the second select remains selected with previous selection and the select is disabled. 

Otherwise, using your other scripts here I tried, when using the broswers back button the 2nd select is not disabled but it shows every option not only those assosicated with the 1st select.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code: http://jsfiddle.net/7qDgZ/9/ it now only show the options assosicated with the 1st selectbox. I hope this is what you need.